# Why likelihood decreasing for GOLEM algorithm

Tags: python, statistics, causality, golem

I was applying the GOLEM algorithm for casual inference using python but for some reason over iterations, my likelihood score is decreasing. Why does this happen?

I have a pretty large dataset with 310127104 rows. I can't perform that because this method is improper for this particular task?

The output looks like this:

```
[2022-06-28 19:18:02,137][golem.py - line 204] - INFO - Started training for 1200 iterations.
[2022-06-28 19:18:04,794][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 0] score=142.987, likelihood=142.987, h=0.0e+00
[2022-06-28 20:46:41,095][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 100] score=141.733, likelihood=141.655, h=9.5e-04
[2022-06-28 22:07:21,093][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 200] score=140.727, likelihood=140.475, h=2.0e-02
[2022-06-28 23:27:34,371][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 300] score=139.868, likelihood=139.517, h=3.2e-02
[2022-06-29 00:48:43,334][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 400] score=138.987, likelihood=138.560, h=4.0e-02
[2022-06-29 02:06:52,349][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 500] score=137.903, likelihood=137.324, h=4.9e-02
[2022-06-29 03:28:45,860][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 600] score=136.425, likelihood=135.597, h=7.0e-02
[2022-06-29 04:53:14,669][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 700] score=135.297, likelihood=134.317, h=8.3e-02
[2022-06-29 06:19:03,769][golem.py - line 217] - INFO - [Iter 800] score=134.337, likelihood=133.297, h=8.3e-02
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and assume you are refering to the "GOLEM" causal structure learning algorithm from [Ignavier et al. 2020](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/d04d42cdf14579cd294e5079e0745411-Paper.pdf).

In their optimization, they minimize a loss consisting of the negative log-likelihood and additional penalty terms (see e.g. equation 3). It is common practice in constraint optimization to use a loss (which has to be minimized) rather than a score which would have to be maximized. This is mostly for reasons of convention and consistency.
For GOLEM, you can see this in the [official implementation](https://github.com/ignavierng/golem/blob/9e99e615c43a288532c319a29ac4bc2a0830226a/src/models/golem_model.py) in line 85. It seems therefore that your model is training as intended (the words "score" and "likelihood" in the output may just be a little imprecise).

##### Note of Caution:

Given that you may be running GOLEM on real-world data, it could be important for you to consider that the excellent empirical results of GOLEM (and a range of similar algorithms) appear to be due to patterns in the benchmarks and likely do not translate to the real-world as shown in [Reisach el al. 2021](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/file/e987eff4a7c7b7e580d659feb6f60c1a-Paper.pdf).